# Mockito: save mock argument and return it from another function

Tags: java, mockito

I want to implement something like this construction.

Main class:

```
public class Connection {

    byte[] read() throws Exception 
    {
      // read some data
      return data;
    }

    void write(byte[] data) throws Exception 
    {
      // write some data
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class ConnectionTest 
{
    private static byte[] mockData;
    private Connection connection;

    public Connection createMockConnection() {
        Connection mockConnection = mock(Connection.class);

        try {
            doAnswer(new Answer() {
                @Override
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    mockData = (byte[]) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                    return mockData;
                }
            }).when(mockConnection).write(any(byte[].class));

            when(mockConnection.read()).thenReturn(mockData);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        return mockConnection;
    }

    @Before
    public void createConnection() throws Exception {
        connection = createMockConnection();
    }

    @After
    public void destroyConnection() throws Exception {
        connection = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallbackConnection() throws Exception {
        byte[] data = new byte[] {1,2,3,4};
        connection.write(data);

        assertArrayEquals(data, connection.read());
   }
```

Saved value `mockData` doesn't contains actual data buffer when I stubbing `write()` and `read()` methods. How I can get actual value passed in `testCallbackConnection()` function?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I mock write() and read() methods in createMockConnection() function:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        mockData = (byte[]) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        return mockData;
    }
}).when(mockConnection).write(any(byte[].

when(mockConnection.read()).thenReturn(mockData);
```

I have real connection, that tested by callback write/read functions and it works fine. Then I want write unit test in case I haven't access to real connection. In this case I create `mockConnection` and stub `write()` (try save passed arg in `mockData` field) and `read()` (return earlier saved in write method arg) methods.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you actually mock the `write()` and `read()` methods?  I don't see this anywhere.  Also, can you articulate to us exactly what you are trying to test?  If you want to test the actual connection, then set up an integration test.  If you want to unit test code which uses the connection, then mock the connection to behave the way you want.

Comment: When you call `thenReturn(mockData)`, mockData is still null, since nobody has called write() on the connection yet, and the answer has thus not executed yet. You need another Answer for read(). But I really don't understand what you're trying to do here. You're testing Mockito, not your code.

Comment: I see, that mockData is still null, when I call stub read() method. But I thought that stub methods calling only when I try to call real method, i.e. my work  logic: 
Call real method connection.write(data) invoke stub method mockConnection.write(data), then I save passed arg (data) to field mockData. After this I call real method connection.read(), that invoked stub method mockConnection.read() and it return mockData field as result.

Comment: If you understand that mockData is still null at this moment, you should understand that your code is thus strictly equivalent to `when(mockConnection.read()).thenReturn(null);`. So you're effectively saying the mock to return null. For the mock to dynamically get the value of mockData **at the time of the read operation*, you need to use an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues with `Connection` notwithstanding, you need to change how you are using the first `Answer` and make use of `thenAnswer()` in lieu of `thenReturn()` for your `read()` method. Basically, your test code isn't seeing the update to the reference of `mockData`.

The new code for `createMockConnection()` is:

```
public Connection createMockConnection() {
    Connection mockConnection = mock(Connection.class);

    try {
        doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                mockData = (byte[]) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                return null;
            }
        }).when(mockConnection).write(any(byte[].class));

        when(mockConnection.read()).thenAnswer(new Answer<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public byte[] answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return mockData;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return mockConnection;
}
```

Note the change to the first `Answer` instance for the `write()` method. The type of the answer indicates the return type. Since the `write()` method doesn't return anything, your `Answer` instance should be of type `Answer<Void>` where your `answer()` method returns `null` because the `Void` type has no instances - only `null` can be cast to it.

Secondly, your `Answer` instance for the `read()` now exists, in lieu of the previous use of `thenReturn()`.

I hope that helps. Ping me with further questions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
when(mockConnection.read()).thenReturn(mockData);
```

to

```
    when(mockConnection.read()).thenAnswer(new Answer<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public byte[] answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return mockData;
        }
    });
```

Now `mockData` contain valid value, that saved in `write()` method and `testCallbackConnection()` passed without errors.

Thank you for help to understanding Mockito stub mechanism.